# Grub rescue error problem!

Tags: grub2

Grub rescue error 
 I got an error on deleting partition (i divided this partition into two partition) of Ubuntu by using easeus partition master

I checked all the partition one by one for grub loader couldn't find...pc says Unknown filesystem

How can I solve this problem!?
I don't have USB or CD!

Comment: grub can't find its modules, you need a LiveCD or USB to fix it

Comment: Please do not spam by adding unrelated tags.